# How to pass a COM object as an IntPtr to a P/Invoke method?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, outlook-addin, mapi

Currently developing an Outlook add-in with Add-in Express, I have to revert to some pure MAPI functions for reading MAPI properties.

Having this P/Invoke wrapper to the [`HrGetOneProp` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842245.aspx):

```
[DllImport(@"MAPI32.DLL")]
static extern int HrGetOneProp(IntPtr pmp, uint ulPropTag, out IntPtr ppProp);
```

I'm trying to pass an Outlook attachment object of type [`IMAPIProp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815525.aspx) as the first parameter to the function.

what I'm currently failing in is how to "convert" that object to an `IntPtr` so that I can pass it as the first parameter to the function. I've tried to use [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr) but obviously this failed with an exception, since I am *not* passing a structure but rather just a reference to an unmanaged COM object.

**So my question is:**

How to successfully call the `HrGetOneProp` method with passing a COM object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the [Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getiunknownforobject.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that any of `Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject`, `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject` or  `Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject` should work

Comment: Thanks, your answer works, too. I decided to vote for the earlier poster, hope you don't mind.